# Сlass for wrapping generic table crashes

Tags: oop, abap

I'd like to build a container ABAP class that wraps an arbitrary internal table.

My initial approach was to define a member variable of TYPE REF TO DATA and pass a reference into the constructor.

The problem is that due to the pointer the instance is still dependent on the original itab. So if the original table is freed from memory you cannot access the data anymore. I'd need to have a real copy of the table data stored within the object, so I would be able to pass the object outside the original scope of the itab.

Is there any way of achieving this in ABAP?

Sample code with references that crashes in the scenario defined in the end:

```
CLASS lcl_test_itab_wrapper DEFINITION LOCAL FINAL
  CREATE PUBLIC.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS: access_outside_itab_scope.
    METHODS: constructor IMPORTING itab TYPE table,
             access_itab_data.

  PRIVATE SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS: sample_itab_setup RETURNING VALUE(result) TYPE REF TO lcl_test_itab_wrapper.
    DATA: table_ref TYPE REF TO data.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_test_itab_wrapper IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD access_itab_data.
    FIELD-SYMBOLS <table> TYPE table.
    ASSIGN me->table_ref->* TO <table>.
    WRITE:/ lines( <table> ).
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD constructor.
    me->table_ref = REF #( itab ).
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD sample_itab_setup.
    DATA: dummy_itab TYPE TABLE OF string.
    APPEND 'test_record' TO dummy_itab.
    CREATE OBJECT result EXPORTING itab = dummy_itab.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD access_outside_itab_scope.
    DATA(o_instance) = sample_itab_setup( ).

    " Here it crashes as the referenced itab was freed already.
    " I'd need to have a real itab copy stored in the instance
    o_instance->access_itab_data( ).
  ENDMETHOD.
```

**Update: Solution** based on @vwegert answer

Replace constructor reference assignment by:

```
CREATE DATA me->table_ref LIKE itab.
FIELD-SYMBOLS <table> TYPE table.
ASSIGN me->table_ref->* TO <table>.
<table> = itab.
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What is there to be gained in the first place?

Comment: The idea was to create a data structure of nodes containing different kind of data that is constructed at one place and then processed at a later stage.

I need to reevaluate whether the CREATE DATA statement already solves my problem without requiring the whole class wrapper.

Comment: You'll probably just add another layer of redundant generics that clutters the code instead of solving any problem. You have a full-fledged data dictionary as well as a strongly-typed class system at your disposal - why go generic without apparent reason?

Comment: The goal is to create renderers for different output formats that work on the same data structure but format the data differently.

They should be able to handle arbitrary (simple, non nested) tables. The actual table contents are up to the calling program, so it is not possible to use any predefined dictionary structures.

The main problem was to create a copy of a generic table, the whole wrapper class was just the initial approach.

Comment: I repeat: If you're using the same data structure anyway, why go generic?

Comment: Please take your time reading the comment instead of providing unconstructive criticism.

They use the same **GENERIC** data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a data object dynamically instead of (ab)using a statically defined one. Check the [documentation of the `CREATE DATA` statement](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/abapcreate_data.htm).

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the statement I've searched.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "GET REFERENCE of xx into xx" statement as well, you can save three lines of your code.